# Is it possible to access a class member in a global function?

Tags: c++

Though I'm sure this is a common issue, I haven't been able to find a thread on this. The closest I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604737/using-member-functions-of-class-in-global-function-before-declaring-object), but it didn't ultimately seem to be asking the same thing.

I'm fairly new to C++, so I may just be doing something dumb.

Say I have the following Person class setup (Sorry for all of the code. I'm not sure exactly where the problem is--if this is even possible--so I'm including everything.):

**person.h**

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Person {
public:
  Person();
  Person(string name);
  ~Person();

  string name;

private:
};

#endif
```

**person.cpp**

```
#include "person.h"

Person::Person() {
}

Person::Person(string name) {
  this->name = name;
}

Person::~Person() {
}
```

Then I want a global function that will change the `name` property of a given person:

**globals.h**

```
#ifndef GLOBALS_H
#define GLOBALS_H

#include <string>
using std::string;

class Person; // forward declaring

void changeName(Person* person, string name);

#endif
```

**globals.cpp**

```
#include "globals.h"

void changeName(Person* &person, string name) {
  person->name = name;
}
```

When I try to compile I get "incomplete class" and "forward declaration" errors (I can provide if necessary). Am I doing something wrong, or would I have to do this using a class member function (e.g. `Person::changeName(.....)`)?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: See the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33437753/is-it-possible-to-access-a-class-member-in-a-global-function#comment54663744_33437802) provided by @Slava. Why are you making a global function instead of a member function? Why aren't you encapsulating the class state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `globals.cpp` file lacks the necessary `#include "person.h"`.

---

There are some other problems, too:

> ```
> void changeName(Person* person, string name);
> ```

This should probably be:

```
void changeName(Person& person, string name);
```

Unless you want to make it possible to call the function with `nullptr`.

> ```
> void changeName(Person* &person, string name) {
>   person->name = name;
> }
> ```

Should be:

```
void changeName(Person& person, string name) {
  person.name = name;
}
```

Then there's this:

> ```
> Person::Person(string name) {
>   this->name = name;
> }
> ```

You should use an initialisation list instead:

```
Person::Person(string name) : name(name) {}
```

And I'm not sure if you are aware of the possibility of passing `std::string` via `const&`. It used to be the guideline for passing strings, until C++11 came along and created ongoing discussions about best practices for passing big objects.

Comment: Actually `changeName` should be a method, with `person` replaced with `this`

Comment: @Christian Hackl Those were exactly the problems. Thank you for your help. Would you mind explaining why  I need `Person& person` instead of my original syntax? My understanding was that I needed to dynamically allocate memory using * since the full class is not defined in the globals file. Then I thought I needed to use &person to alter person.name directly and not simply a copy of the value. Obviously that was not quite the case.

Comment: @Slava - Yeah, I realized it could be done that way (and that was what I used in the meantime while I worked this out), but I was more or less curious as to whether this approach could be taken instead, depending on how I wanted to implement it. Would that be pretty much universally true that it should be a method? In my program, I wanted to do it this way because I wanted it to be more or less a "world" action taking place on the Person, rather than the Person doing its own name-changing, if that makes any sense.

Comment: "Would that be pretty much universally true that it should be a method?" Well, this is a whole point of OOP - encapsulation.

Comment: @rrr45 technically it can be done, you already have answer why it did not compile for you. But implementing that way is against one of the main principle of OOP - encapsulation.

Comment: @Slava Yeah, I realize it *can* be done the way the accepted answer stated (as I noted, it worked), my followup question was just one of best practices. But now you've answered that one as well--I need to just keep this as a method. I'll keep the method implementation in that case. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @rrr45: You do not *need* `Person& person`. It's just a superior solution because you eliminate the possibility of receiving nothing (= `nullptr`) and do not have to handle that special case. Forward declarations work perfectly with pointers and references; the full class definition would be required to construct a `Person` and thus to dynamically allocate one. I think you should learn these two things (forward declarations / dynamic memory management) separately. They are not as closely related as you seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

For a start the following:

```
Person(string name);
```

should be

```
Person(const string& name);
```

For performance

And `string name` should be in the private bit,

Also then signature for

```
void changeName(Person* person, string name);
```

in the header differs from the code in the .cpp file

i.e.

```
 void changeName(Person* &person, string name) {
```

Also put in the `#include` as stated by the other person

Comment: Can you explain why `const string&` is preferred? Also, why should the name be private? In my case specifically, I would like any person's name to be accessible outside of the class. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: @rrr45: I think an introductory book on OOP would be in order. `private` members are an absolute core feature of C++. For example, how would you ensure that no `Person` can have an empty name?

Comment: @rrr45 you need `const string&` to eliminate useless copy operation. It is not required in this case but it is a good practice for optimization.

Comment: @rrr45 - This is elementary stuff - better you get a book and read about it

Comment: Thanks everyone. Sounds like I need to brush up on OOP.